# How to Zip Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to zip the dataframe of pandas and make it a list.

```
list(zip(dataframe['a'], dataframe['b'], dataframe['c'],
            dataframe['d'], dataframe['e'], dataframe['f'])
```

This is the final result I want to make.

```
[('q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y'), (...)]
```

The above code works, but it looks very messy and dirty.

So, I am looking for a way to simplify the code by using the Comprehension method or other methods.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it works but you want a cleaner approach I'd suggest taking a look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: May be you want `list(zip(*[df[col] for col in df]))`.

Comment: Thank you @SandeepKadapa! It works very well!

Is there a way to make a list from the second column to the last column?

Comment: @MeetTitan Thank you. Let me check what you said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
list(zip(*[df[col] for col in df]))
```

OP's request to start from second column:

```
list(zip(*[df[col] for col in df.iloc[:,1:]]))
```

Or

```
list(zip(*[df[col] for col in df.columns[1:]]))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a list from the second column to the last column?

Comment: `list(zip(*[df[col] for col in df.columns[1:]]))`

Comment: Thank you very much!! @jezrael , SandeepKadapa

Comment: @M2KS Please [`accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solution provided your required result.